# Number of conjugacy classes of $G/[G,G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, derived-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite group. We can define a relation $R$ on $G$ by setting $aRb \iff b = g^{-1} a g$ for some $g \in G$. The conjugacy class of an element $a \in G$ is defined as its equivalence class:
$$[a] := \{b \in G: \hspace{0.1cm} aRb\} = \{g^{-1}ag \in G: \hspace{0.1cm} g \in G\}$$

Let $[G,G]$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$, defined to be the subgroup generated by elements of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, $a,b \in G$. I want to prove that the number of conjugacy classes of $G/[G,G]$ is $|G/[G,G]| = |G|/|[G,G]|$ but I have no idea how to prove it. I believe I have to use the fact that $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, but that's all I know. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $aRb \iff b = g^{-1}ag$ for SOME $g \in G$.

Comment: Ops. You are completely right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjugacy classes of an abelian group all have exactly one element, therefore the number of conjugacy classes of a finite abelian group $H$ is equal to the number elements of $H$.

Comment: Oh, right! This is because if $G$ is abelian $g^{-1}ag = ag^{-1}g = a$, so $[a] = \{a\}$ right?? So easy and I didn't notice it!

Comment: Yeah exactly! Nice!